# boost-spirit numeric parsers and getting the desired synthesised attributes

Tags: c++, parsing, portability, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

**--edit -- Solved the question : a comment on the last sidenote would be helpfull. Also comments on phoenix::bind overload handling would be helpfull (in my answer).**

I'm working on a system with strict typing requirements, I want to ensure that I am parsing integers that meet the constraints of int32_t and int64_t, I wan't the parsers to synthesise and constrain the parsed strings to the mentioned types.

How do I go about this ? The [document](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/int.html) mentions that `long_long` is only available on platforms with 64-bit support, but I need to parse int64_t's on 32-bit platforms as well.

An excerpt from my parser is as follows:

```
...
  eps(_b == VALUE_INT4) >> qi::long_ 
    [phoenix::bind(&AddEntry, _r1,_a, _1, _pass)] ) // 
| ( eps(_b == VALUE_INT8) >> qi::long_long)
...
```

AddEntry has a `int32_t` overload and a `int64_t` overload, is a [phoenix::static_cast_](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/starter_kit.html#phoenix.starter_kit.construct__new__delete__casts) on `_1`in order ? And if this is the case how do I parse 64-bit integers on a modern 32-bit platform ? I assume `BOOST_HAS_LONG_LONG` is only not-defined on archaic hardware like the [8008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8008) ;) .

`<Rant>`
I wish they had stuck with the standards set out in c99 and `<boost/cstdint.hpp>`, most of us want to program against clean abstractions. There are probably good reasons for the numeric parsers being defined the way they are. however, grand-scheme use could be better defined in the documentation.
`</Rant>`

**On a side note:** Does the conditional epsilon style above rival a case statement in performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Qi parsers already check for overflow conditions. The parser component will fail if the input is not representable by the type the component is supposed to match. For instance, `int_parser<int32_t, 10>` will fail for numbers not fitting into a signed 32 bit integer.

You can use the `long_long` parser (i.e. the predefined 64 bit integer parser) only if `BOOST_HAS_LONG_LONG` is defined. If you have a platform where this is not the case, you can still emulate a 64bit integer by writing your own wrapper type exposing the functionality as expected by Qi numeric parsers (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/int.html#spirit.qi.reference.numeric.int.minimum_expression_requirements_for__code__phrase_role__identifier__t__phrase___code_)), for instance:

```
struct my_64bit_int {
    //...
};
typedef int_parser<my_64bit_int, 10> my_64bit_int_parser_type;
my_64bit_int_parser_type const my_64bit_int_parser;
```

and use it as:

```
my_64bit_int bigint;
parse(b, e, my_64bit_int_parser, bigint);
```

2) You can't bind overloaded functions without helping the compiler, i.e. given:

```
void AddEntry(int32_t);
void AddEntry(int64_t);
```

you need to cast the function pointer explicitly if you want to bind for an `int32_t`:

```
phoenix::bind((void(*)(int32_t))&AddEntry, _1);
```

Answer to sidenote: No. The alternative parser is always sequentially executing the different alternatives in the same sequence as specified, stopping when the first of those matches. Its overall complexity is `O(N)`, where `N` is the number of separate alternatives (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/alternative.html#spirit.qi.reference.operator.alternative.complexity)).

Comment: Thank you as always Hartmut :D on the side-note, I was expecting O(N), however I was worried about the internals, I would be concerned if the implementation made `N` function calls for `N` conditionals, in function condition-checking would be what I would expect (like a case statement, unless I misunderstood how a case statement works).

Comment: To elaborate, `switch(xtype){ case(int): break; case(string): break; }` is what I have tried to implement with `( eps(x_type == int) | eps(x_type == string) )`. If the constructed parser had to make a function call internally to evaluate the `eps(condion)` for each element the overhead might be prohibitive.

Answer (score 0):

These templatas will get you the semantics you want.

```
qi::int_parser< int32_t,  10, 1,10>  p_int32_t;
qi::int_parser< int64_t, 10, 1, 19> p_int64_t;
```

These parsers were unit tested and created expectation errors on overflow --i.e., when `>= 2^31` and `>= 2^63` respectively.

Overloads aren't picked up by phoenix::bind afaik (**correct me if I'm wrong please**),

therefore a macro along the lines of

```
#define  ADD_ENTRY(TP,prefix)                                           \
    void AddEntry_##prefix( value_variant_vector & v, uint32_t ordinal, \
                            TP entry, bool & ok_)                       \
```

For those interested the compiler error message is as follows (when AddEntry is a template function):

```
/opt/dev_64_swat/dsl/src/parser/RowAndTable.cc:43: error: no matching function 
for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const
boost::phoenix::actor<boost::spirit::attribute<1> >&, const 
boost::phoenix::actor<boost::spirit::local_variable<0> >&, const 
boost::phoenix::actor<boost::spirit::argument<0> >&, const   
boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::argument<2> >&)’
```

I get errors on hand written overloads as well.